# class not found: running successfully in eclipse but throws exception at command prompt

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

interface Payable {
    public void getAmount(int x);
}

class HEmployee implements Payable {
    public void getAmount(int x) {
        System.out.println("Amount paid to Hourly employee is Rs.::" + (x * 120));
    }
}

class WEmployee implements Payable {
    public void getAmount(int x) {
        System.out.println("Amount paid to Weakly employee is Rs.::" + (x * 820));
    }
}

class J40 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Payable refer;
        HEmployee h1 = new HEmployee();
        System.out.println("Enter the Hourly employee worked Hours::");
        int h = s.nextInt();
        refer = h1;
        refer.getAmount(h);
        WEmployee w1 = new WEmployee();
        System.out.println("Enter Weakly employee worked Hours::");
        int w = s.nextInt();
        refer = w1;
        refer.getAmount(w);
    }
}
```

Running Succesfully in **eclipse** but throws exception at command prompt.

Saved by name `J40.java`

`javac J40.java` successful.

`java J40` throws exception

Comment: Please reformat your question and please show your Exception

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: What exceptions it throws?

Answer (score 0):

I can able to run you code through command prompt without getting any exception

[image]

No modification i have done.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run the code in Eclipse and command prompt. I have divided each interfaces and classes into individual files, and the `import java.util.*;` should be in J40 class.

Below is the command line I run.

```
C:\Test>javac J40.java

C:\Test>java J40
Enter the Hourly employee worked Hours::
12
Amount paid to Hourly employee is Rs.::1440
Enter Weakly employee worked Hours::
2
Amount paid to Weakly employee is Rs.::1640
```

Comment: I don't think even in one file it will make any difference .